# How to move a Divi module into a child theme for later customization?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to move (better: copy) a standard Divi module, in this example the text module, to a child theme so that my customization to come survive an update.
First step is to simply add the module to the child theme and use it. Of course there shouldn't be any change in functionality in the back-end, front-end or in the visual builder. BTW: I'm using Divi 4.4.2 and builder version 3.17.3

What I tried so far:
I created a child theme, created the folder "Divi-Child" and added the style.css (empty so far) and functions.php:

functions.php:

```
<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function divi_child_theme_setup() {
    if ( class_exists('ET_Builder_Module')) {
        get_template_part( '/custom-modules/ctm' );
        $ctm = new WPC_ET_Builder_Module_Text();
        remove_shortcode( 'et_pb_text' );
        add_shortcode( 'et_pb_text', array($ctm, '_shortcode_callback') );
    }
}
add_action('et_builder_modules_loaded', 'divi_child_theme_setup', 9999);
```

I created a folder for the "custom" modules (custom-modules).
I copied the php content from the Divi original module (path in main theme: /Divi/includes/builder/module/text.php) into my custom-modules folder and called the file ctm.php (custom text module).
In this file I changed the class name from `ET_Builder_Module_Text` to `WPC_ET_Builder_Module_Text`.

I expected, that everything would work just as before. And it nearly was like that:

- The module works correctly on the website. Even with little changes (like adding some text to a text template) it works fine.
- I can change it's properties when using the visual builder by selecting the module and clicking the edit button.
- No changes to be noticed in the back-end or other modules or the visual builder itself.

BUT: the module isn't rendered in visual builder mode. Instead, the following line is output on every location a text module appears:

```
function(t){
  return r.a.createElement(f.a,E({rawContentProcesser:h.default.replaceCodeContentEntities},e.props))
}
```

I don't know how to handle that situation.
My question is:
Is there a way (this way here or any other) to copy Divi standard modules to a safe place where customization don't get overwritten by the next update?

If needed I can provide the whole ctm.php (which is the same as the Divi Text.php).
I had a longer chat with elegant themes support (days), but they couldn't provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Divi module override process for Divi 4+ here (I just test it with FilterablePortfolio and it's working fine) :
[Moving Blog module in Child theme](https://help.elegantthemes.com/en/articles/4532734-moving-blog-module-in-child-theme)